# Camel - Keeping a copy of the message

Tags: apache-camel, jbossfuse, apache-servicemix

My camel route is as follows (sample)

from (activemq:xyz)   --- Receive the message from a QUEUE

to(smpp:abc)  --- Submit the message to SMSC

to(cxf:hij) ---  Based on SMSC response as success call the webservice

The problem I am facing is as below

I have few exchange properties/headers received from the queue, but after receiving the response from SMPP, my exchange headers/properties that I have sent are cleared and not available for me to call the webservice.   What can I do to keep these values to be as it is untill I reach the end of route.   I have no control on the SMSC implementation and cannot change the SMSC response.  I am using SPRING dsl

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can consider using the enterprise integration pattern named [Content Enricher](http://camel.apache.org/content-enricher.html) for the SMPP part, with a custom `AggregationStrategy` that 'keeps' your original exchange (with all the headers and properties), and takes what you need (the body, I presume?) from whatever SMSC does.

```
from (activemq:xyz)
    .enrich(smpp:abc, new PreserveHeadersAndPropertiesAggregationStrategy())
    .to(cxf:hij)
;
```

with

```
public class PreserveHeadersAndPropertiesAggregationStrategy implements AggregationStrategy {
    @Override
    public Exchange aggregate(Exchange original, Exchange resource) {
         // use body from getIn() or getOut() depending on the exchange pattern...
        original.getIn().setBody(resource.getIn().getBody());
        original.getOut().setBody(resource.getOut().getBody());
        return original;
    }
}
```

Comment: I read about content enricher, and it says "The content enricher (enrich) retrieves additional data from a resource endpoint in order to enrich an incoming message (contained in the original exchange). An aggregation strategy is used to combine the original exchange and the resource exchange. The first parameter of the AggregationStrategy.aggregate(Exchange, Exchange) method corresponds to the the original exchange, the second parameter the resource exchange."  So the resource end point should be a from end point, which is not in my case .. I need to send to SMSC and get a response

Comment: You can indeed send and receive a response via `.enrich()` - if you look at the diagram, there are "to" and "from" arrows going to/from the resource (in your case, smmp:abc). The original exchange gets sent "to" and the resource returns "from", whilst the aggregation strategy gives you some choice of how you "merge" the result - I think it should work, please try it :)

Comment: Glad to hear it, Joe!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a bean and store the headers and properties you would like to preserve in a thread-local member. A simple example that keeps and restores all headers/properties could look like this:

```
public class BeanToHoldHeadersAndProps {
    ThreadLocal<Map<String,Object>> headers = new ThreadLocal<>();
    ThreadLocal<Map<String,Object>> props = new ThreadLocal<>();

    public void saveHeaders(Exchange exchange) {
        headers.set(exchange.getIn().getHeaders());
        props.set(exchange.getProperties());
    }

    public void restoreHeaders(Exchange exchange) {
        exchange.getIn().setHeaders(headers.get());
        exchange.getProperties().putAll(props.get());
    }
}
```

Route:

```
<camel:route id="header_preserving_route">
    <camel:from url="activemq:xyz" />
    <camel:bean ref="headerPreserver" method="saveHeaders" />
    <camel:to url="smpp:abc" />
    <camel:bean ref="headerPreserver" method="restoreHeaders" />
    <camel:to url="cxf:hij" />
</camel:route>
```

Depending on your requirements there is a third element you might want to carry over, which is the attachments of the exchange.

Comment: How will i pass exchange to a bean ?

Comment: He showed you in the example: `camel:bean`. PS: he needs to save properties also.

Comment: @vikingsteve Thanks for pointing out my omission of the properties. I have updated my answer.